# What are the best online writing classes?

Tags: technique, resources

I've taken some classes at Mediabistro.com -- both nonfiction -- and while the teachers have been pretty good (one gave me some excellent advice that led to publication in national magazines) ... the students have been, well, really bad. And part of the online class experience (or any class experience for that matter) is the people you're studying with. What online writing classes have you taken, and would you recommend them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been pretty happy with [Gotham's online classes](http://writingclasses.com).